# Create Trunk/Branch&Tag structure after first commits

Tags: svn

We have a svn server sucesfully running since a couple of years.
We structure everything in one repository, with the structure:

```
--Project 1
  --trunk
    --source
  --branch
  --tag
--Project 2
  --trunk
  --branch
  --tag
```

Unfortunately, somebody created a project without the trunk/branch/tag structure. So now we have

```
--Project 1
  --trunk
    --source
  --branch
  --tag
--Project 2
  --trunk
  --branch
  --tag
--Project 3
  --source
```

What would be the preferred way, to move the folders into the right folder structure, without losing the file history (quite some commits were already done on project 3).
We're using svn plugin within eclipse, but Tortoise or commandline is also fine.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create the `trunk`, `tags`, and `branches` folders and move the existing `source` folder into the `trunk` folder.

Here are two ways how you can achieve this:

- Using the Repository Browser in Tortoise SVN:

  - Open the Repository Browser and browse to your "Project 3" folder.
  - Create the `trunk` folder.
  - Move the `source` folder into the `trunk` folder by dragging it onto the `trunk` folder.
  - *Note that this will create multiple revisions: one for creating each folder, and another one for moving the folder.*
- Using your local working copy:

  - Create the `trunk`, `tags`, and `branches` folders locally.
  - Add the folders to Subversion.
  - Commit the folders to the repository (it is safer to commit the folders before moving the `source` folder into the trunk).
  - Right-click the `source` folder and drag it with the *right* mouse button still pressed onto the new `trunk` folder.
  - In the context menu select "SVN Move versioned item(s) here".
  - *Note: It is important to use "SVN Move" (using right-button-drag) and not the normal move from Windows Explorer (using left-button-drag) because otherwise your SVN history will be lost!*

Comment: thank you, I went with the first version, and it worked like a charm